# External stylesheet not overriding bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I wanna change the style of some elements which are affected by the bootstrap classes of the parents element.
-I put the link of the stylesheet below the one of bootstrap
-I even moved the .css file outside the html's folder as adiviced in a similar topic but it still doesn't work
(IF I PUT THE CODE IN THE INTERNAL STYLESHEET IT WORKS INSTEAD)

For now I'm just trying to remove the style from the list

BE AWARE: running this code from the snippet is gonna show you no issues, however on the browser it doesn't actually work

Here's the code

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">

  <!--
    <style>
      ul{
        list-style-type:none;
      }
    </style>

      -->
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a class="active" href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
              <li>
                <a href="/blog.html">Blog</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/digitalNomad.html">Digital Nomad</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/about.html">About</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ul>
          <li>Facebook</li>
          <li>Instagram</li>
          <li>Twitter</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at **[CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)** rules. Just because you define a rule doesn't automatically mean it overrides a rule declared earlier.

Specificity is calculated on 4 factors `abcd`:

```
a     (1 if inline, 0 if in a file),
b     number of IDs in CSS rule
c     number of attribute selectors, classes and pseudo-classes,
d     number of element names and pseudo-elements.
```

The rule with the largest 4 digit number `abcd` wins and overrides lesser declarations, so inline declarations will override anything declared in an included CSS file.

Other CSS Specificity articles

- [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)
- [Specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/)

**Possible Solutions**

It's generally not a good idea to change 'base' styles or to override Bootstrap styles directly.

1. You can  override other declarations by adding `!important` to your rules, but this is generally regarded as a poor solution.
2. Add your own class and/or id to elements which you wish to customise.
3. If you wish to have a quick effect, then you can add your own specific `id` or `class` to the `body` element and then declare your rules relying on descendents of that `id` or `class`. Using an `id` in this way will give your rules a specificity of `01xx` in a file, which will probably be enough to override Bootstrap rules.

e.g

CSS in file:

```
#mypage ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body id="mypage">
...
   <ul>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: but why if I write that rule in the internal stylesheet it works and if I write the same one in the external it doesn't??

Comment: See expanded answer, essentially inline declarations trump any declaration in a file

Comment: the code I posted is copied/pasted. An inline or internal stylesheet would easily solve a "bug" but not the problem itself. Restyle every webpage with internal or inline declarations is gonna take too long and it is unproductive. I need to find the core of the problem

Comment: The core of the problem has been described to you, and in addition I have proposed some solutions

Comment: vogomatix don't misunderstand me. I'm thankful for your replies and I'm checking out what you said right now but haven't solved the issues yet. That's why I'm keeping the topic open, cause if the solution result to be related to something else whoever is gonna have the same issue can than solve it

Comment: added id as you said. Still not working. Do you reckon there might be some plugins or something that has to be installed? I'm a newbie so I leave any option open

Comment: I've added a proper example using my last answer, which I've tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that your external style sheet is actually being loaded? If it works when written in the internal style tag, but not in an external file, it sounds like that file isn't loading properly. That could be an issue with the file name, the path to the file, or even an invalid structure of the file itself.

Comment: The path is correct, CTRL + click (using visual studio) open directly the linked file. As it is working it means the path is correct and I doubled checked it by myself to be sure

Answer (score 0):

Include your own stylesheet above the bootstrap link

```
<link rel"stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I had this problem a lot of times, this works for me every time since the CSS stylesheet above is preferred over the one below

Comment: if I put it above the compiler is gonna prioritize bootstrap, not my stylesheet. It works the other way around

Comment: I'll create a project and test to see which way it works

Comment: You're correct, but when i did the same thing on a pre-made button class in materialize(a framework), it worked
I'll add my code after my initial answer

Answer (score 0):

Further to my last answer, this works fine in Chrome:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myrule.css">
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Tests</title>
 </head>
 <body id="mypage">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- rest of your html here -->
```

myfile.css just contains:

```css
 #mypage ul {
    list-style-type:none;
 }
```

Comment: The problem was simply the equal symbol missing in the declarations of the link of my .css file. Sometimes we are so focused on the logical part of the code that we forget it may simply be a syntax error. Sorry about that. I don't know how to close the topic but it can be closed. Thank you everyone!